# Loop Through column and multiply a cell by a number if Condition is met Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops

[Output Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4wRB.jpg)[Original Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgY1J.jpg)I need to loop through column A and if the cell contains the numbers 500 or 600 or 700 i need to multiply column F by -1 to make it negative so -500, -600 or -700. Column F being a duplicate of Column A.

Ex Column A3 is 500 and F3 is 500 i want to make F3 -500

```
'loop through and multiply 500,600,700 by -1
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lr
    If UCase(Cells(i, "a")) = "500" Then Cells(i, "f")*(-1)
    If UCase(Cells(i, "a")) = "600" Then Cells(i, "f")*(-1)
    If UCase(Cells(i, "a")) = "700" Then Cells(i, "f")*(-1)
      
Next i
```

Comment: You say "I need to loop through column A and if the cell contains the numbers 500 or 600 or 700 i need to multiply it by -1" but your code tries multiplying cells values in column F:F. Are there in column F:F the same values like in A:A? if Yes, why not iterating in F:F? If not, please clarify the issue. What is the problem of the code you posted, against the question expressed in words?

Comment: `Select Case Cells(i, "A").Value`, `Case 500, 600, 700`, `Cells(i, "A").Value = Cells(i, "A").Value * -1`, `End Select`.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to specify, If column A contains 500,600 or 700 then multiply that cell in column F by -1 yes supposing that columns is a duplicate of column A but would rather use column F to multiply by and leave column A untouched.

Comment: Still not sure I correctly understood... So, **should F:F column become a A:A duplicate, but with the required modifications regarding multiplication**?

Comment: Column A and F already contain the same data, except i want to modify column F by making it negative if it contains 500,600,700 in column A hope that helps

Comment: Then, try the code I posted. F:F may be identic, or may be empty. The result will be the same...

Comment: What you write is ambiguous. *If col `A` contains `500` or `600` or `700` then multiply col F by `-1` to make it negative*.  However, if Col `F` is already negative, then multiplying by `-1` will make it positive.  Do you want to toggle back and forth?  Do you want something else?  Edit your question to clarify your description, and also provide examples of original data and desired results.  Also, why are you using `Ucase` in your code?  And if col F is a duplicate of Col A, there's no need to reference Col A at all.

Comment: Ok just copied the table example i am using and what i need it to do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It will clone the A:A range, but values of 500, 600, 700 being multiplied with -1:

```
Private Sub MultiplyMinus1SomeValues()
   Dim astRow As Long
   lastRow = Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   With Range("F2:F" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=IF(OR(A2=500,A2=600,A2=700),A2*-1,A2)"
        .Value = .Value
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This turned all cells in column F negative

Comment: @DalAnalyst This is possible only if all values in A:A are or 500, or 600, or 700... Is this the case? It is a simple evaluated formula... If not anything confidential, can you share the workbook you try processing? At least a picture of the sheet in discussion...

Comment: Hmm not all of my cells in Column A contain either one of those three numbers so it should only by multiplying F if it finds 500,600 or 700 in column A but it multiplied each cell in column F by -1 not sure why.

Comment: @DalAnalyst  I asked for something... Is it possible to share anything from what I was asking about? I tested the above code and it works as it should. That's why I would like to see what you try processing...

Comment: @DalAnalyst I found a mistake in the code. Let me adapt it...

Comment: @DalAnalyst Please, try the updated code and send some feedback.